# Unable to start Tomcat 10 with https connector

Tags: java, webserver, https, tomcat

I have just installed tomcat 10 and tried to integrate a jks file that i have been using in a tomcat 9 installation with no issue, but i was unable to start the tomcat 10 with it.
Can anyone please provide a working https config for tomcat 10 i would prefer if it was with a jks file but i would be happy with pem, crt, p12 or any other certificate format.

below are the error that i have got while trying to start the tomcat 10 with jks file.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no element SSLHostConfig found with hostName [_default_] corresponding to defaultSSLHostConfigName for the connector [https-jsse-nio-8443]
```

Answer (score 0):

<< Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no element SSLHostConfig found with hostName [*default*] corresponding to defaultSSLHostConfigName for the connector [https-jsse-nio-8443]

The above error message is mostly triggered when you are using some deprecated SSL attributes such as 'keystoreFile', 'keystorePass' which are no longer available in Tomcat 10, refer [1]

Attributes like keystoreFile and keystorePass are marked as deprecated in Tomcat 9 and removed completely from Tomcat 10.

You can include the certificate details inside the  tag as shown below

```
<!-- Define an SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    port="8443"
    maxThreads="150"
    SSLEnabled="true">
  <SSLHostConfig>
    <Certificate
      certificateKeystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore"
      certificateKeystorePassword="changeit"
      type="RSA"
      />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

[1] https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#SSL_and_Tomcat

[2] https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-Connector-NIO_and_NIO2(deprecated)

[3] https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-Connector-APR/Native(deprecated)

Regards,
Bharat